# Problem with QtWebKit 4.7.2 on Symbian^3 device

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, qtwebkit, nokia-n8

I'm currently writing a QML application using the Qt SDK 1.1 beta and I'm making use of QtWebKit. The application works fine on Windows and within the simulator, but when I try to run it on a Symbian^3 device (N8), I get the following error:

```
[Qt Message] file:///C:/Private/ef18eef4/qml/qml/inlinehtml.qml:42:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtWebKit": The file 'C:/resource/qt/imports/QtWebKit/qmlwebkitplugin.qtplugin' is not a valid Qt plugin. 
     import QtWebKit 1.0 
     ^
```

This is also the case with any of the QtWebKit examples that I try to run. I installed qt.sis and qtwebkit.sis found in QtSDK\Symbian\sis\Symbian^3\Qt\4.7.2 to the device.

Any ideas on what could be causing this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
import Qt 4.7
import org.webkit 1.0
```

?

Comment: I get the following error for desktop/simulator and device debugging:
`module "org.webkit" is not installed 
     import org.webkit 1.0 
     ^`